# What is the missed part on this java code

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I'm trying to do simple interacting interface, I linked the following method with the button by android: onClick so I should when I click the button it should display the alternative image and Text, but when I click on the button nothing happens, what is the missed part here

```
 public void eatCookie(View view) {
    // TODO: Find a reference to the ImageView in the layout. Change the image.

    ImageView eated = new ImageView(this);
    eated.setImageResource(R.drawable.after_cookie);
    TextView eatedtext = new TextView(this);
    eatedtext.setText("i'm so full");
  TextView eatedText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);

    // TODO: Find a reference to the TextView in the layout. Change the text.

}
```

Comment: I see no button and no listener added. Please show that code.

Comment: post your full code

Comment: Notice that your code comments mention finding references to `View`s in the layout, and setting a text/image on those. That's not what that code is doing. It's creating new `View`s, ones that aren't on-screen, and setting properties on them.

Comment: here you are the  xml code
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="EAT COOKIE"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:onClick="eatCookie"
        />

Comment: thanks for helping out 
this is the right answer
 public void eatCookie(View view) {
        // TODO: Find a reference to the ImageView in the layout. Change the image.


       ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.android_cookie_image_view);

        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.after_cookie);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
        text.setText("i'm so full");



        // TODO: Find a reference to the TextView in the layout. Change the text.

    }

Answer (score 1):

**First problem:**

Suppose, you created TextView and ImageView:

```
ImageView eated = new ImageView(this);
TextView eatedtext = new TextView(this);
```

In your Activity, I'm sure that you use or xml layout, or custom ViewGroup, so you missed the code, where you adding `eated` and `eatedtext` to your layout by calling [`addView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View)) method.

**Second problem:**

If we suppose that you really created views and added them, then you still have a problem, because you didn't specify layout params for `eated` and `eatedtext` by calling [`setLayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)) method.

**Solution**

I think you need to write something like:

```
ImageView eated = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.eated_image);
eated.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
eated.setImageResource(R.drawable.after_cookie);

TextView eatedText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
eatedText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
eatedText.setText("i'm so full");
```

And in your xml you need to set for those views attribute `android:visibility="gone"` or `android:visibility="invisible"`

Comment: that's the button xml code, 
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:text="EAT COOKIE"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:onClick="eatCookie"
        />
i think the problem is the second problem you have just mentioned, how could i add param to this objects ?

Comment: And? Ok, I saw xml snippet of your button. The problem isn't in it, problem is that you didn't add views to your layout

Comment: As I said earlier you can use method 'setLayoutParams'. For example, eated.setLayoutParams(...). But also you need to add this view to your layout. What kind of Layout do you have in xml?

Comment: thanks for helping out 
this is the right answer
 public void eatCookie(View view) {
        // TODO: Find a reference to the ImageView in the layout. Change the image.


       ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.android_cookie_image_view);

        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.after_cookie);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
        text.setText("i'm so full");



        // TODO: Find a reference to the TextView in the layout. Change the text.

    }

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you have defined the TextView in the layout-XML. If so, you don't have to create a new `TextView` object but instead alter the existing.

```
    TextView eatedText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
    eatedtext.setText("i'm so full");
```

Comment: here is the full xml code, 
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s534/sh/55914e58-629c-484d-84ec-19e98d84d0b7/bf598461fa9a760c96f48ae77ae6bcad

so can you tell me where is the problem because i created and linked them and nothing is showing up

Comment: thanks for helping out 
this is the right answer
 public void eatCookie(View view) {
        // TODO: Find a reference to the ImageView in the layout. Change the image.


       ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.android_cookie_image_view);

        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.after_cookie);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
        text.setText("i'm so full");



        // TODO: Find a reference to the TextView in the layout. Change the text.

    }

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
public void eatCookie(View view) {
    // TODO: Find a reference to the ImageView in the layout. Change the image.

    LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    setContentView(linearLayout);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    ImageView eated = new ImageView(this);
    TextView eatedtext = new TextView(this);
    eated.setImageResource(R.drawable.after_cookie);
    eatedtext.setText("i'm so full");

    linearLayout.addView(eated);
    linearLayout.addView(eatedtext);

    // TODO: Find a reference to the TextView in the layout. Change the text.

}
```

Comment: thanks for help, this worked for the image but the position of the image is not prefect, also the text didn't show up, what is the problem

here is the full xml code 
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s534/sh/55914e58-629c-484d-84ec-19e98d84d0b7/bf598461fa9a760c96f48ae77ae6bcad

Comment: create XML or view programmatically , you just need anyone no. let me check the XML

Comment: what is the problem in the xml

Comment: thanks for helping out 
this is the right answer
 public void eatCookie(View view) {
        // TODO: Find a reference to the ImageView in the layout. Change the image.


       ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.android_cookie_image_view);

        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.after_cookie);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
        text.setText("i'm so full");



        // TODO: Find a reference to the TextView in the layout. Change the text.

    }

Comment: didi you got the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please read the comments

```
 public void eatCookie(View view) {
    // TODO: Find a reference to the ImageView in the layout. Change the image.

    ImageView eated = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.android_cookie_image_view);
    eated.setImageResource(R.drawable.after_cookie);

    TextView eatedText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
    eatedtext.setText("i'm so full");

}
```

Update your XML File `android:layout_height="0dp"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/android_cookie_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/before_cookie" />
```

Comment: here is the full xml code, i still new to programming android and can't figure out what is the problem 

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s534/sh/55914e58-629c-484d-84ec-19e98d84d0b7/bf598461fa9a760c96f48ae77ae6bcad

Comment: this is worked only for the text, the image didn't change dude !

Comment: thanks for helping out 
this is the right answer
 public void eatCookie(View view) {
        // TODO: Find a reference to the ImageView in the layout. Change the image.


       ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.android_cookie_image_view);

        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.after_cookie);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
        text.setText("i'm so full");



        // TODO: Find a reference to the TextView in the layout. Change the text.

    }

Comment: ok thats great if you figure out the problem. add your solution as answer to your own question.

Comment: done bro, still new to android sorry for bothering you

Comment: hey sohail, i'm trying to post this question on stack overflow but it says doesn't meet  our quality standard, this is the question>> 

   hey folks i have a question  
if i need to add a button to do some change for a while and then the app back to the default situation     
for example : in a workout app   

if i pressed the button of "start" the app give me pic of running person for a 10 seconds and the automatically pack to the original pic the question is how can i do such thing in android ?     
''thanks in advance''>> 
can you tell me what is the wrong with it?

Comment: @ebnrdwan stack-overflow is for help if stuck somewhere or you need a expert advice or find something like your question in google easily and implement it if you face some issue while implementing it then post a question with concise info along with some related code. so you are welcome here.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helping out folks.

Here is the right answer, as you mentioned you don't need to identify the identified object in the xml code file like `ImageView` and `TextView` so the right code will be

```
 public void eatCookie(View view) {
        // TODO: Find a reference to the ImageView in the layout. Change the image.
        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.android_cookie_image_view);

        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.after_cookie);
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text_view);
        text.setText("i'm so full");

        // TODO: Find a reference to the TextView in the layout. Change the text.

    }
```